# Conflicting types with a declared int func

Tags: c

Reading Kernigan, and the given code doesn't seem to work because of 'conflicting types' error for the user function.

The compiler I'm using is cc 7.4.0. I've declared the function in the beginning and have been checking and re-checking the types seemingly forever. Guess I'm missing something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);

main()
{
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        ;
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; i < (lim-1) && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
func.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
 int getline(char line[], int maxline);
     ^~~~~~~
In file included from func.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:616:20: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
 extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                    ^~~~~~~
 ^~~~
func.c:25:5: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
 int getline(char s[], int lim)
     ^~~~~~~
In file included from func.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:616:20: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
 extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getline` is already declared (in error actually) in `<stdio.h>` and its signature differs from yours.

The simplest thing to do is to rename your version to something different.

Answer (score 2):

You need to block the compiler from spewing non-standard crap into standard headers. You are using some compiler which has defined a non-standard `getline` function inside the standard library header `stdio.h`, which is non-conforming.

With gcc you should compile as for example `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I always love reading your answers - they are enough to make compiler vendors tremble. +1, of course

Comment: This is going to give OP an error on `main()`. He is not using the most up-to-date ressource to learn. (Maybe mention that in your answer?)

Comment: @uneven_mark Which is a good thing... the problem is that K&R is outdated and not a good source for learning modern C.

Comment: @Lundin: Shall we do this again?

Comment: @Lundin Sure, but OP doesn't seem to know that and will not understand the new error message. GCC is not very helpful in indicating what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Bathsheba Regarding compiler vendors, they are stuck between a rock and a hard place... namely the C standard and the POSIX standard. Which aren't compatible and POSIX is to blame, not the compilers.

Comment: @uneven_mark Be that as it may, the best advice I would give to beginners (and veterans all alike) is to compile with strict settings and all warnings enabled. If they don't understand a compiler message, just ask Google or SO.